# MIME type issue in InternetExplorer using Proxy

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, proxy, mime

In Internet Explorer, the requested url is being blocked due to mime type mismatch. The scenario is that request is being sent from the client to the destination server through proxy server. Suppose we have A(Client), B(Proxy Server), C(Destination Server). The request goes from A(client) to B(Proxy server) and from B(Proxy server) to C(Destination server). Similarly the response also comes from C(Destination Server) to B(proxy server) and from B(proxy server) to A(client) from where the request was initiated. Now the problem is that the response Content-type is "application/liquid" but the client fires the request using the "script src=proxyserver/test" , so the excepted Content-Type for response becomes "text/javascript". It is not allowed to change the Content-type of response from "application/liquid" of the destination server. The whole scenario works perfectly in all the other browser and the response is easily accessible. However in IE as we are getting the error as "request blocked due to mime type mismatch " . So can anyone provide the solution that how could we make it work ? 
Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Comment: What is your "Accept" header for that request? Is it an AJAX request or a regular request?

Comment: Regular request !!! Called through script tag...

Comment: "Called through script tag" - can you add the code that issues this request? Have you taken into consideration the answer written below?

Comment: Yes I've taken into consideration the answer below. Which code from where we add the script tag or what I'm getting in the response.

Comment: The code that initiates the request or, both - more information would be helpful. Or you can tell us know to reproduce the issue if it is a publicly accessible web page.

Comment: This is a publicly accessible web page so you can reproduce the issue by clicking on the link "https://nirma.myshopify.com/" and check in the console.

Comment: I see no errors in IE 11 just going to the page. Please see: https://pasteboard.co/H1p5Aws.png - are there any additional steps?

Comment: The error is already visible in the screenshot which you've seen It is the last line "SEC7112".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a script , an external script which will give the call to the desired code using a ajax call or xmlhttprequest , where you will need to set the accept header so the desired mime type. So from the client it will call  that external script using the script tag which will get executed through the proxy server and which will further give the call to the actual data and recieve its response and send back to client. But as it will call the script, by default header would return as text/javascript and the error will get resolved.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** - you will need to change the mime types.

This problem appears when the requests expected type is different from the response-content type (as indicated by the headers). The correct solution would be to make response and request headers compatible with each other. That means, the call you make "*through a script tag*" should be changed to have the same `accept` header as the response's `content-type` header.

Also, take a look at the documentation:

> nosniff Blocks a request if the requested type is "style" and the MIME
>   type is not "text/css", or "script" and the MIME type is not a
>   JavaScript MIME type.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options).

I see that this URL: https://nirma.myshopify.com/apps/GeoShippingBar/geoShippingBarProxy has this content-type: `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8` which is not *javascript-mime-type*.

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not working.Yes I understand that nosniff asks for the exact mime type match but the problem here is the proxy code has liquid code and javascript code, so in order to get the liquid code executed , I have set the content-type as "application/liquid" which by default reads the content type as "text/html". In this case what should i do to match the mime type. The error only occurs in IE , not in Chrome or FireFox. It is working correctly in others.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

response.addHeader("accept","text/javascript");

set in the response of script tag from where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot do this. App Proxys are meant for creating pages not script files.

A possible strategy that will get you where you want to go is as follows:

The dynamic from liquid parts can be put into a snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascrpt">
   geoShippingConfig = {
       somevalue: '{{ shop.X }}',
       etc
  };
</script>
```

And you inject that into the main layout when your app is installed. Various apps do this sort of thing. You have to warn the customer that you are going to to that but it's fairly benign. You also need a refresh button or some way to re-inject the snippet and the include when the theme changes.

Then your app installs a Script Tag with your code instead of calling an app proxy. Script tags include the shop in the url so you can do any app specific config to the returned script file. Your script tag script uses geoShippingConfig on load.

Comment: The App Proxy is also meant for doing the changes in the store from different server. I know that this is possible to creating a snippet but I want to do that using app proxy and it's very much possible. It is already working in all the other browsers except IE. If u can provide the solution for IE it will better but please do not say that It's not possible.

Comment: What you cannot do is change the mime type. If you set the content-type of your proxy response to applicationéliquid then Shopify returns it to the browser as textéhtml. One thing you could try would be to make sure the url your a requesting has a .js extension. This may cause Shopify to treat the response like a .js.liquid asset file.